# How to include models from local files into existing world? (ROS2)

Tags: ignition-fortress

I'm trying to include a [pioneer model](https://app.gazebosim.org/OpenRobotics/fuel/models/Pioneer%202DX) into an existing .sdf world using <include>, but the [existing documentation](http://sdformat.org/tutorials?tut=spec_world&cat=specification&#models-defined-in-other-files) is less than clear about how to do things (and simply using the names of the packages didn't work) and the [gazebo tutorials](https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/fuel_insert) only cover inserting from fuel. I tried several little variations of the examples (such as using the name specified in model.sdf and adding "model://" before either name), but nothing worked.

Can someone tell me how to properly include models from other files into a .sdf world, or at least point me at some obscure tutorial that explains this properly? Thanks in advance.

Edit: found how to fix it. The model directory must be renamed to the model name specified on the model.sdf file.

Comment: If you found the answer, it is preferred to write this in an answer and accept it, rather than editing the question. That way, the question is marked as 'answered'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model directory must be renamed to the model name specified on the model.sdf file, and must be in the same directory as the world file using it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really for pioneer, but came across this while trying to figure out generally how to go from URDF to SDF (and google took me here for some reason :-)

I created robot.urdf.xacro and then:

- xacro robot.urdf.xacro > robot.urdf
- gz sdf -p robot.urdf > robot.sdf
- Add following to main SDF file for Gazebo:

```
<include>
    <name>Robot</name>
    <pose>1 1 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <uri>file://robot.sdf</uri>
</include>
```